# When I create a new project, I get an error in the console

Tags: unity-game-engine

Can you help me? I do not understand why these message appear in the console when trying to create a new Unity project:

```
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
Unity.PlasticSCM.Editor.ProjectDownloader.ParseArguments.GetOrganizationNameFromData (System.String data) (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.collab-proxy@2.0.3/Editor/PlasticSCM/CloudProjectDownloader/ParseArguments.cs:42)
Unity.PlasticSCM.Editor.ProjectDownloader.ParseArguments.CloudOrganization (System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[TKey,TValue] args) (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.collab-proxy@2.0.3/Editor/PlasticSCM/CloudProjectDownloader/ParseArguments.cs:24)
Unity.PlasticSCM.Editor.ProjectDownloader.CloudProjectDownloader.DownloadRepository (System.String unityAccessToken, System.String[] commandLineArgs) (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.collab-proxy@2.0.3/Editor/PlasticSCM/CloudProjectDownloader/CloudProjectDownloader.cs:63)
Unity.PlasticSCM.Editor.ProjectDownloader.CloudProjectDownloader.DownloadRepository (System.String unityAccessToken) (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.collab-proxy@2.0.3/Editor/PlasticSCM/CloudProjectDownloader/CloudProjectDownloader.cs:51)
Unity.PlasticSCM.Editor.ProjectDownloader.CloudProjectDownloader.Execute (System.String unityAccessToken) (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.collab-proxy@2.0.3/Editor/PlasticSCM/CloudProjectDownloader/CloudProjectDownloader.cs:43)
Unity.PlasticSCM.Editor.ProjectDownloader.CloudProjectDownloader.RunOnceWhenAccessTokenIsInitialized () (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.collab-proxy@2.0.3/Editor/PlasticSCM/CloudProjectDownloader/CloudProjectDownloader.cs:32)
UnityEditor.EditorApplication.Internal_CallUpdateFunctions () (at <e3d2e3f6a525465bbf8c67432a3cb6ef>:0)
```

But is not influential in my project. I am still afraid that there is an error in my project

Answer (score 0):

Unity swears at Plastic SCM, I think you don't use it. You could try deleting it via the window>package manager in the drop-down menu and select the assets in the project. Find and remove Plastic SCM.